# Calculate % of two columns Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-custom-visuals

I want to calculate % of two columns which are already in %.

I want to calculate formula like

Target achieved= ACTUAL/TARGET

But here is ACTUAL is already a measure/calculated metrics so I'm not able to divide these two columns.

Any help would be appreciated..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure both target and actual are actually numbers and not strings. You can do it in transform data (aka Power Query) part, before data is loaded into the report.

[image: data transformation]

After that you should be able to create the measure you want, e.g. something like that:

[image: measure % completed]

**UPDATE** : What happens if Actual is not a column, but a measure?

If Actual measure is based on the columns in the same table as target you shouldn't have a problem. You cannot combine measure and column in the same formula. Measure is an aggregated field and needs to be grouped by another field (if you are familiar with SQL,think of SUM and GROUP BY). Coming back to your problem, you need to create measure out of "Target" column as well (notice I have in the formula SUM('Table'[Plan]) which makes it a measure). Than you can use both of them in the formula, but of course you need to "group" them by something(e.g. date) otherwise it will just show you a total.
[image: formula with Actual as measure]

Comment: Thank you! In my table, Actual & Plan both are in %. But the Actual column is not in my columns/fields list because it's also a new measure. Now when I'm trying to add a new measure "% completed" but not able to use the "Actual" pre calculated measure in my new measure -"% completed. How can we calculate % ratio of one measure & one column?

Comment: Added an update that should answer your question